# UILocalNotification in sleep mode on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, multitasking, uilocalnotification

I'm developing a Voip application.

When I press the lock button(app goes to sleep), and the server sends a request I present a local notification.
The local notification is presented as it should and The button slider text says "slide to answer". If I slide here, the app gets open.

However, if now I press again the lock button, and then unlock, the notification is still presented and the slider text has changed to "slide to unlock".

Now, when I slide to unlock, it's as if I pressed the "close" button on a regular notification bar, meaning the app won't open.

My question is why on the second time the local notification is still presented ? and if so, is there a way to track the unlock button event or the unlock slider so I can tell the server that I don't want to answer the call ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notification is only a dialog (i.e., the user can interact with it directly) for a short time - until the device is locked again, either by using the button or automatically after a time-out of about 15 seconds.

After that, it turns into a notification. The user cannot interact with it directly, apart from reading the message.

Sorry, but it doesn't get any better unfortunately.

Comment: How do you explain the fact the when my app is in the background and a local notification is presented, pressing the lock button, and then unlocking, pretty fast (below the 15 seconds that you claim the notification will disappear), make the notification disappear. however, when in sleep mode, and notification presented, locking and then unlocking would still render the notification on screen just without any action possible ?

Comment: Like I said, it's either the time-out OR pressing the lock button. Same effect. Both effectively cancel (or rather, ignore) the dialog options.

Comment: By the way, the scenario with app-in-background-but-not-locked is new to me, my answer doesn't discuss that. But I'd venture a guess that that is also a case of "doesn't get any better".

Comment: And another thing, I don't claim the notifications disappear. They just turn into messages instead of dialogs.